# Open Excel document from a powerpoint presentation (VBA, powerpoint)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to open an existing excel document in the same directory with an ActiveX button during my presentation. The code

```
Workbook.Open "Dokumention.xlsx"
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `Workbooks.Open FileName:="SOMEPATH\Dokumention.xlsx"` Workbook***S***.open

Comment: I still get a runtime error 424 with the remark that an object is required

Comment: If all you want to do is open an Excel document by a button click, VBA is overkill.

Comment: Adding to John Coleman's comment: Simply create a hyperlink to the file. Make sure the file's in the same folder as your PPTX before creating the hyperlink. That'll make it more likely that the link will still work if you move the files to another location/computer, so long as you keep them together in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the object first.

```
Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xExcelApp.Visible = True
Set wb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("SOMEPATH\Dokumention.xlsx")
```

Before you run it you need to enable the reference MS Excel 16.0 Object Library
[image]